How to upload locally located files to Teams with visual basic code
I am having trouble uploading a locally located pdf file to teams as a different name with visual basic code.
Sub CopyFileAndRename()

Dim srcURL As String

Dim destURL As String

srcURL = "C:\Path\To\Your\banana.pdf"

destURL = "https://Companysharepoint.com/sites/msteams/apple.pdf"

CopyFile srcURL, destURL

End Sub

When I run this code in teams, I get error 76 and it says path not found. Do I need to authenticate separately to upload to teams?

You could sync your Teams files to One Drive and you can then use a local path to upload to Teams.

So I typically avoid this from VBA; I have used ShareGate in the past to perform this, where too many files/locations were being utilized for individual linking through a OneDrive.

If you sync the Teams folder to your local PC you can move the file to the synced local folder.  https://www.berkshirecc.edu/knowledge/microsoft-office/sync-teams-files.php#:~:text=Open%20the%20%22Teams%22%20panel%20and,channel's%20files%20to%20your%20computer.

@KJ - I agree this is a major annoyance/risk with syncing folders, which is why I don't really use or recommend it much, except for cases like this where someone needs to interact with a SP/Teams library programmatically.

You said that when I sync my Teams folder to my local PC, I can move files to the synced local folder, so why can't I move files when I sync to my local PC?
